# Modal con altura dinámica y footer

Tags: css, ionic

¡Hola!

Tengo una ventana con una altura dinámica y scroll. El problema es que el footer no se puede visualizar ya que la lista de datos ocupa toda la pantalla. Me gustaría ver siempre el footer.

¿Alguna idea?

Este es mi código css:

```css
.own-modal { 
  @media (min-height: 320px) { 
    ion-backdrop { 
      visibility: visible; 
      } 
    }
     
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;
     
    contain: strict; 
    .modal-wrapper { 
        &, .ion-page, 
        .ion-page .content,
       .ion-page .content .scroll-content { 
          contain: content; 
          position: relative; 
          top: auto; 
          left: auto; 
        } 
        display: flex; 
        overflow: auto;
        flex-direction: column; 
        max-height: 100%; 
        opacity: 0; 
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%; 
    } 
}
```

El contenido de la ventana modal es muy sencillo. En el tag del content tengo un label y una lista y después tengo un footer con un div y dentro del div, un item con un botón.

Comment: Te recomiendo que insertes tu código completo en un snip de manera que podamos ver el problema y podrias utilizar `z-index`

Comment: La ventana modal tiene z-index y el componente footer también

Comment: Si se pone position: sticky al footer parece funcionar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en el archivo css correspondiente se pone el siguiente código el footer queda estático al final de la página:

> ion-footer {    position: sticky; }

Más información sobre esta propiedad:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: Hola IreneC, gracias por contestar. Aunque esta publicación puede servir de guía para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido reportada por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de información: ¿dónde pondrías el `position:sticky` en el código de la pregunta? ¿por qué o cómo resuelve el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos para contestar una pregunta correctamente. Los tendré en cuenta en el futuro :)

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente ejemplo coloca un div en el pie de la página o contenedor y permanece fijo no importa la altura del elemento padre.

Utilizando `z-index` te aseguras que el elemento se posicione por encima de otros.

```html
<div class="footer" style="
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FFBBAD;
  line-height: 3.5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #00214B 
  z-index: 999;
">
 <button style="line-height:30px;margin-top:10px;margin-left:5px;"> OK </button>
</div>
```